# Upgrading Subversion on Debian Lenny from 1.5.1 to latest (1.7.0)

Tags: linux, svn, debian

I am trying to upgrade Subversion on my webserver, Debian Lenny machine. I do an apt-get install subversion and it tells me subversion is already at the newest version. The latest version on Subversion's web site is 1.7.0. What do I need to do get the latest version on my server?

Comment: why close... SF and SU just split the community, not to mention this question could legitimately belong on any unix, linux, programming, coding, server, or user related exchange site (i.e. any of them). -.-

Answer (score 3):

It's not yet packaged in the Debian [repositories](http://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=subversion&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all).

You should build it from [source](http://subversion.apache.org/download/#recommended-release), installing to `/usr/local` (the default prefix for a custom build).

Comment: This was attempted, however, to many issues popped up with the ./configure (including APR, libtool and autoconf issues). Too many to deal with, so for now, i'll stick with what is working. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Building SVN is a PITA. 1.6 had subversion-deps, did you have any luck with this?

Answer (score 3):

try installing it from [this](http://opensource.wandisco.com/debian/dists/) repository.

Answer (score 2):

You have a couple choice: you could go here: http://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=subversion and see that 1.6.12 is available as a Debian package in backports (newer software for older OS).  Or if you really want the latest, download the source from the Subversion site and build it yourself according to their instructions.

I would try the Debian packaged 1.6.12 first, and only attempt building it myself if there were a very good reason.

Comment: This was also attempted, however, to many issues popped up with the ./configure (including APR, libtool and autoconf issues). Too many to deal with, so for now, i'll stick with what is working. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

I just built subversion-1.7.2 without any problems, and I don't really know what I'm doing. I'm running a distro based on Debian squeeze (Crunchbang statler) and I didn't have to worry about dependencies

1. Download the latest tar.gz from the [Apache site](http://subversion.apache.org/download/#recommended-release) (to e.g. ~/downloads)
2. Unpack and enter the directory (e.g. `cd ~/downloads; tar -xvzf subversion-1.7.2.tar.gz; cd subversion-1.7.2`)
3. Get the dependencies with `./get-deps.sh`
4. Configure apr and apr-util `cd apr; ./buildconf; cd ../apr-util; ./buildconf; cd ..`
5. Set up configure with `./autogen.sh`
6. Run the generated configure with `./configure`
7. If that didn't work, search for the missing packages in the package manager, and install everything. You may need to create a new terminal window in order for the install to be noticed.
8. Build and test with `make; make check`
9. As root, install with `make install`

And you should be ready to go! I'm not sure if this works for a server, but I definitely have a working client.

Answer (score 0):

I just built svn 1.7.0 and all dependencies (including APR) on AIX. I encountered issues at the end of the build (make install) when it attempted to relink mod_dav_svn and mod_authz_svn (install could find the files, for cryin' out loud). Had to execute the final commands manually to finish the install.